# Beats input plugin makes Logstash container exit

Tags: docker, logging, elastic-stack, filebeat

Recently I've been working around Logstash and a centralized logging solution. I managed to gather a bunch of log files from different applications and log them to Elasticsearch with the help of the file plugin provided by Logstash.

The problem occured when I tried using Filebeat. I'm running Filebeat and the whole ELK Stack in different containers. Everything is running fine except for Logstash when I use the beats plugin.

If I change my Logstash configuration (logstash.sample.conf) to be like this:

```
input
{
   beats{
       port => 5044
   }
}
```

When I restart my Logstash container it will immediately exit. I currently have no clue of what can be causing the container to crash and that is where I need help.

I can't also find any logs from logstash inside the container that can help me figuring out what is going on.

My filebeat (filebeat.yml) configuration is the one below:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /Users/henriqueferreira/Documents/LogCollection/sharing/*.log

output:  
  logstash:
    hosts: ["127.0.0.1:5044"]
```

**Has someone seen this problem recently and is able to help me out? What could be causing the container to exit?**

Comment: Please check your docker logs. docker logs <container_name>

Comment: If you don't have any output, try changing the command of your container to a sleep command and run logstash manually. It has to tell something to explain its failure